# Not working 24h time format in Full calendar (v5)

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I don't understand the problem.
Found the solution in the official documentation.
I have version 5, and it shows AM, PM format. I need to change it to 24 hours.
I found other ways to solve but not for version 5.

```
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                height: 1100,
                initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
                initialDate: '2021-06-18', // will be parsed as local
                allDaySlot: false,
                eventsTimeFormat: {

                    hour: '2-digit',
                    minute: '2-digit',
                    second: '2-digit',
                    meridiem: false
                },
                eventSources: [
                    // Events
                    {

                        events: [
                            {
                                title  : 'SimulatorName',
                                start  : '2021-06-18T12:30:00',
                                end: '2021-06-18T14:30:00',
                            },
                            {
                                title  : 'SimulatorName',
                                start  : '2021-06-13T12:30:00',
                                end: '2021-06-13T14:30:00',
                            },
                            {
                                title  : 'SimulatorName',
                                start  : '2021-06-13T15:30:00',
                                end: '2021-06-13T19:30:00',
                            },
                          
                        ],
                        color: 'silver',
                        textColor: 'black',
                        borderColor: 'black',
                        eventTimeFormat: { // like '14:30:00'
                            hour: '2-digit',
                            minute: '2-digit',
                            second: '2-digit',
                            meridiem: false
                        },
                    },

                ],
            });
            calendar.render();
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `eventTimeFormat`, not `eventsTimeFormat`. - as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventTimeFormat . Always double-check your work carefully.

Also to get a 24hr display then, again as per the documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting, linked from the eventTimeFormat article), you need to specify `hour12: false`

```
eventTimeFormat: {
  hour: "2-digit",
  minute: "2-digit",
  hour12: false
},
```

will get you a conventional 24hr display - e.g. 3.30pm will be displayed as 15:30.

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/VwpNRdo

Answer (score 1):

For V5

```
new FullCalendar.Calendar(document.getElementById('js-calendar'), {
    eventTimeFormat: {
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      hour12: false
    },
    slotLabelFormat: {
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      hour12: false
    },
    ....
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
            eventTimeFormat: {
                hour: "2-digit",
                minute: "2-digit",
                hour12: false
              },
              slotLabelFormat: {
                hour: '2-digit',
                minute: '2-digit',
                hour12: false
              }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).